# Iterating over the elements of two 2D lists in python and printing the difference

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two 2D lists:

```
list1 = [[]]
list2 = [[]]
```

and in a loop I iterate over a bunch of registers and do write operations and then readback operation and get the populated lists.

```
list1.append([regName,writeValue])
list2.append([regName,readValue])
```

Now I want to compare these two lists to make sure that my readback values from the registers are the same as the ones I wrote. I am doing something like this for that:

```
for (x,i),(y,j) in itertools.izip(list1,list2):
    if [x][i] != [y][j]:
        print >> myfile, 'MISMATCH: reg_name = %s, expected_value =0x%x, actual_value =0x%x' % (x,i,j)
```

This is of course wrong and gives me an error saying `ValueError:need more than 0 values to unpack`.

How do I compare the write and read values for the same corresponding register name in the two lists and print any mismatches?

Comment: are you only trying to figure out if they are not the same, or you need to know the specific indexes that are not?

Comment: I want to know what specific indexes corresponding to the regName that are not the same and what the expected and actual values are.

Answer (score 0):

I started using your method and noticed the result:

```
>>> list1 = [[]]
>>> list2 = [[]]
>>> list1.append(['a',1])
>>> list2.append(['a',2])
>>> list1
[[], ['a', 1]]
>>> list2
[[], ['a', 2]]
```

I then ran the comparison:

```
>>> for (x,i),(y,j) in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
        if [x][i] != [y][j]:
            print "Doesn't match!"



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    for (x,i),(y,j) in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Maybe itertools is creating two empty lists?  That might be causing the problem.

Comment: I don't think so as my list is fully populated.I printed and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

1: the way you start `list1` and `list2` with an empty list is what is causing your error!

2: That is not your only problem!

When you fix your list assignment code and run it, you will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

that is because in your `for loop`, you are making your variables `x` `i` `y` `j` be the elements in the list and trying to index them, and you can't do that. I am not really even sure if the syntax you use is okay...the following will do what you want:

```
for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
    if x is not y:
        # do what you want here
```